# Jomsocial profile issues with Joomla core SEF

Tags: joomla2.5, profile, joomla-sef-urls, jomsocial

- I have a strange issue with JOMSOCIAL and Joomla core SEF.

  - Once I enabled Search Engine Friendly URLs that creates a trouble with Jomsocial Profile
  - It only loads only jomsocial profile page even if I click photos, videos, groups in the jomsocial menu bar.

This issue would be solved if I disable Search Engine Friendly URLs. But I'd like to use Search Engine Friendly URLs.

Here is the URL of the site :

http://poolavadi.com/home/ta/account/myaccount.html

Login info :

User name : test

pass      : test@123

please use the url to goto the issue page after logging in since the whole site will be in my language. I've put jomsocial only in English.

Comment: Hi, I am closing the above links for now. If anybody's got better ideas please share, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue above can be fixed by going to the sef404 configuration screen and unchecking optimization. Depending on your own setup you can uncheck other options as well. Also be sure to check your 404 manager within sef404 and make sure there are no duplicate links. If so make sure the id matches the menu id . Assuming you understand what matching your menu id to correct option  in 404 manager.

Comment: thank you. and I fixed this issue after changing few lines in a php file

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue. Which lines did you change in order to fix this?